# Windows On Screen Keyboard(osk.exe) freezes on mouse down on OSK title bar

Tags: c++, windows, mousedown, on-screen-keyboard

I have one C++ application which converts touch events to mouse input. I'm using  **SendInput** API to send mouse events on a Windows 7 (32/64-bit) system.  For allowing users to enter characters in applications I am using the built-in Windows **on-screen keyboard (osk.exe)**.

Any mouse down event generated by my application that happens **when the cursor is over the window decoration of the OSK window (title bar, system menu, etc) freezes the mouse**. It seems only the mouse down event is processed, as I can see OSK get focus. My application keeps sending other mouse events but they have no effect on the OSK window. The only way out is to press/release the physical USB mouse attached to the system.

The strange thing is that using OSK for entering characters by sending mouse presses on the OSK keyboard buttons from my application is working fine. It's just that trying to move (or close) the OSK window freezes the mouse handling.

As a solution, I tried below things :
(1) Make **uiAccess=true** in manifest file of my application
(2) Application code is already signed
(3) Application resides in a trusted location

But still problem occurs.

If I run my application as an **Administrator**, then it works fine. But I don't want my application to start as "Run as Admin".

Any suggestion?